# mongodb insert field in single array document

Tags: php, mongodb, mongodb-query, database

I have a document in mongodb that looks like this

```
{
   "_id": ObjectId("5378da275ad972a811c119fb"),
   "name": "test test",
   "fname": "test",
   "lname": "test",
   "phone": "13254355554",
   "user": "525518965ad972636d7aa0ae",
}
```

And i want to insert a new field for "employee_id" so the result should be exactly like this.

```
 {
   "_id": ObjectId("5378da275ad972a811c119fb"),
   "name": "test test",
   "fname": "test",
   "lname": "test",
   "employee_id": "09872",
   "phone": "13254355554",
   "user": "525518965ad972636d7aa0ae",
}
```

I have used $push and $addToSet but the results became an array like

```
"employee_id": {
     "0": "09872",
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use [`$set`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/set/);

```
db.test.update(
      { _id:ObjectId("5378da275ad972a811c119fb") },    // Update this id only 
      { $set:{"employee_id": "09872"} }                // by setting employee_id
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the [**`$set`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/set/) operator, `$push` and `$addToSet` are for arrays:

```js
db.collection.update({}, {'$set': { "employee_id": "09872" } })
```